# setNeedsDisplay and subviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

From my understanding, `setNeedsDisplay` only affects the view it's called on. Is there a simple way to say "update this view and all its subviews, recursively?"

In response to the comments, here's my situation: I've got a custom view

```
@interface ContainerView : UIView
```

this view does *not* implement `drawRect`. In my xib  there's an instance (called `container`) of the `ContainerView` which has some (custom) subviews added to it.  When in the code I say

```
[container setNeedsDisplay]
```

I expect these subviews to update. Where am I wrong?

Comment: `setNeedsDisplay` should trigger the update of all sub-views of a view. Could you share the code where this is not happening?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I've updated my question, please take a look

Comment: "setNeedsDisplay should trigger the update of all sub-views of a view" -- no, that is not the case. `-setNeedsDisplay:` affects only the view that receives that message.

Comment: `setNeedsDisplay` does trigger `drawRect:` on all of its subviews. I just did this to a superview and the breakpoint in a `drawRect:` of a subview was triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, UIView draws itself when its first displayed. CALayers do not. Calling setNeedsDisplay on a UIView marks it as dirty, this automatically redraws all SubViews as well (calling drawrect on all subviews). Calling setNeedsDisplay on a CALayer doesn't have the same effect, it wont redraw sublayers. Hope this helps.

Regards

Ref
*iOS 7 Programming Pushing the Limits By Rob Napier, Mugunth Kumar*

Answer (score -1):

[UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

> The UIView class defines a rectangular area on the screen and the interfaces for managing the content in that area. At runtime, a view object handles the rendering of any content in its area and also handles any interactions with that content
>
> setNeedsDisplay
>   Marks the receiver’s entire bounds rectangle as needing to be redrawn.
>   Note: If your view is backed by a CAEAGLLayer object, this method has no effect. It is intended for use only with views that use native drawing technologies (such as UIKit and Core Graphics) to render their content.

The subviews are inside the bounds of the view, so the view will ask it's subview what to display.
Have you try and encounter some case that go agains this definition?
If you are implementing your own UIView subclass you need to handle all the display yourself in `drawRect:`

Comment: @thg435 - Why are you Subclassing UIView if you don't implement `drawRect:` ?  And what kind of update are you expecting, drawing refresh ?

Comment: I expect subviews' drawRect methods to be called automatically when I say `[container setNeedsDisplay]`